# Split not working correctly in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, split

Check this out

```js
alert("wtf/http://google.com".split('/', 2));
```

the resulted array contains 2 elements: `wtf`, `http:`.

Shouldn't it have `wtf` and the rest of the string? :/

Comment: "limit: Optional. Integer specifying a limit on the number of splits to be found. The split() method **still splits on every match of separator**, but it truncates the returned array to at most limit elements." -- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: wow... you set up, that you want only 2 element and complaining that you get only 2... nice!!!

Comment: To do a single split, you might be able to use `.split(/\/\/)` instead. Unless marked as global (`/g`), a regex will only match once.

Comment: weird, I didn't expect that. In PHP explode doesn't work this way :|

Comment: you set a limit=2 on the split function

Comment: Jeremy: that doesn't seem to work. I still get the 2nd part cut off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd value passed to the split function limits your results but not where the array is split. To clarify the split separates it into 4 sections first then only returns the first two.

If you're trying to split out the wtf and the url try the following:

```js
alert("wtf/http://google.com".split(/\/(.+)/,2))
```

Comment: This code shows what the OP actually wanted and expected from split, it answers the question indirectly by saying that you need more logic to make this work. However it doesn't fully answer why the OP's approach is flawed.

Answer (score 1):

The last integer in the function call specifies that split will return only two pieces. You just need to increase that number to 4, or remove it entirely.

```js
alert("wtf/http://google.com".split('/'));
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're splitting on the '/' and there are 4 slashes. It's just splitting up to the next '/' it finds, which would be '//google.com'.

If you do:

```
alert("wtf/http://google.com".split('/', 4));
```

you'll get all the pieces, just not separated into 2 chunks the way you want